# Is there a way to rebuild a binary linked to a static library

Tags: makefile, build, static-libraries

I'm working on the software that is being built on the RHEL using Makefile's. The build system is producing both .a (static libraries) and .so (dynamic libraries). Those libraries are independent pieces of the huge program.

If I change a source code of the binary and run the build I will rebuild the binary and everything will be good. But if I change the source code inside the .a library (one of the files that produce the library) and try to build, the build system will regenerate the library only. It will not relink the binary the .a file is linking to.

Is there any special flag I can use to force the `make` command to relink the binary that needs to be re-linked?

TIA!

Comment: Sounds like your binary doesn't declare the lib as an input in your build-system

Answer (score 1):

`make` is just a tool that executes a makefile.  The actual build rules are part of the makefile, and it is up to the makefile author to write correct [rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Rules.html). In your case, it seems that the makefile author neglected to list the static library as a prerequisite (dependency) in the rule that builds the binary. This means that make will not automatically relink the binary if the static library changes.

Depending on the complexity of your build system, this could be quite difficult to fix, or it could just be a matter of adding `libfoo.a` to the list of dependencies of the main binary.